# C# - .NET 4.x Расширение интерфейса

Tags: c#, .net, интерфейс

Как возможно расширить интерфейc IEnumerable ?
Надо что бы метод возвращал каждый второй элемент таблицы.
Желательно с примерами =)
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы предложил сделать так:

- Написать метод для `IEnumerable<T>`, а не просто для `IEnumerable`. Тогда можно будет получать типизированный результат.
- Решить общую задачу: получение каждого n-го элемента. Это будет универсальное решение, которое легко использовать для получения каждого 2-го элемента.

Код:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetEveryNth<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
    {
        if (n <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n");
        int index = 1;
        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            if (index % n == 0)
                yield return element;
            index++;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetEverySecond<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.GetEveryNth(2);
    }
}
```

Демонстрация:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var a = Enumerable.Range(1, 6).ToArray(); // 1 2 3 4 5 6
    // Получаем каждый второй элемент
    foreach (var x in a.GetEverySecond())
        Console.Write(x + " "); // 2 4 6
    Console.WriteLine();
    // Получаем каждый третий элемент
    foreach (var x in a.GetEveryNth(3))
        Console.Write(x + " "); // 3 6
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за столь подробный ответ и комментарии ! Не зря зарегистрировался ! Стремление к знаниям столько же, сколько и информации ) Но ничего, пока студент - буду учить, Могу сказать, что теперь stackoverflow мой 3ий дом !)

А теперь по теме.Надо почитать про параметры расширяющих методов. Я думал, что можно применять только 1 параметр.( А тут целых два уже ) И наверное, мне стоит лучше изучить интерфейс IEnumerable =( А так могу сказать - огромное спасибо !

Answer (score 7):

Смотря какие вы преследуете цели. Если это продакшн-код, то можно  написать метод расширения. Собственно, весь Linq синтаксически построен вокруг методов расширения к этому самому интерфейсу.

Выглядят методы расширения как статические методы в статическом классе, при этом принимающие в качестве первого параметра экземпляр "расширяемого" класса или интерфейса с модификатором this. Например так:

```
public static class EnumerableExtension 
{
    public static IEnumerable EverySecond(this IEnumerable en)
    { 
         // некая логика
    }
}
```

Если это учебное задание, то скорее всего препод будет рад, если вы напишете и реализуете интерфейс, наследующийся от IEnumerable и определите таковой метод в нем. Что-то такое:

```
public interface IEnumerableExt : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerable EverySecond();        
}


public class EnumerableExt  : IEnumerableExt 
{
    public IEnumerable EverySecond()
    { 
         // некая логика
    }    
}
```

Comment: Угу, причём второй метод явно проигрывает первому: (1) существующие классы? (2) существующие функции, возвращающие итератор?

Comment: @VladD появился для Вас тут вопрос =) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429605/blolb-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B8-mp3-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c